# Does anyone know of a way to easily convert a PDF to a docx format programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, pdf, docx

We have a couple 3rd party systems that give us PDFs.  We would like to convert those PDFs for display on the web without using an Adobe product.  Ideally we would like to use Silverlight to render the PDFs but are having trouble converting from a PDF to Xaml or using docx format as a middle man.  There are lots of libraries that give PDFs but that is not what we need.

If there is a library out there that does this, a .net lib would be preferable but we can run the conversion using the command line as well if that is an option.

Comment: Anyone know of any free options native to .net instead of running 3rd party apps (i.e. ghostscript)

Comment: Yes, the Mono project implements many of the required classes.  I'm not sure where it currently stands with respect to Silverlight, but the plan is to implement all the relevant classes.

Answer (score 2):

[Aspose](http://aspose.com) sells .Net converter libraries.

Comment: They have nothing that can convert a PDF to doc, docx, RTF, or anything similar

Comment: @JTtheGeek Erm, Yes they do. You can export to DOCX, XLSX or PPTX using this library. https://products.aspose.com/pdf/net

Comment: @Mark, correct, Aspose has greatly expanded their offerings since the original question and we use almost all of their products now, they are fantastic.

Comment: I actually upvoted this because, from my tests with the Aspose PDF for .NET -- in 2020 -- it looks like they are doing the right thing: the PDF to SVG converter did preserve the vector paths intelligently.

Answer (score 1):

Convert PDF to SVG (ghostscript will do it) and import that as a series of images: I'm not a .net programmer, but I understand that can be done with the system.io.packaging class, which, for what it's worth, is implemented outside of .net by the Mono project.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you don't actually need to change anything in the pdf documents you can use pdf.js which renders pdf documents as html 5. For more info please see this blog post.

http://andreasgal.com/2011/06/15/pdf-js/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of converters from PDF to XPS which is a subset of XAML.

[update] some reference links

- [What Is The Structure Of a XPS File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690004/what-is-the-structure-of-a-xps-file)
- [XPS or XAML viewer to embed in .NET app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425605/xps-or-xaml-viewer-to-embed-in-net-app)